# Using entity framework with custom subclasses

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am using the C# entity framework to map data to sql server for a project. I am trying to figure a way to use the entity framework to automatically produce custom subclasses based on a discriminator field while not requiring the sub classed entities to have tables.

Example:

In entity framework I have a object `A` which has a field `type`. I also have the following

```
public class B : A {
}

public class C : A {
}
```

I am looking for a way to make entity framework recognize that the `type` field is for example `B` and then create an instance of the `B` class. The classes have no data that needs to be persisted to the database. They are just wrappers for rows in a different table.

Example:

I have a table of item objects. Each item object has a collection of item settings and an item type field.

There are different types of items (Text, Radio, Checkbox) and they are all rendered differently using an abstract `render()` method. Each of these subtypes also has a certain set of item settings that are required for that object.

If I could create entity subclasses without having to map them to a database I could have a TextItem be a subclass of Item, implement my `render()` method and the add properties that map to each of the values in my item settings table. Then when im pulling a new item from the database, based on the type field it would create my specific class automatically based on a discriminator.

I have done this sort of thing using DBML. I would like to use the entity framework as it is more powerful, but there may not be a way to do what i'm looking for.

Comment: Its seems odd what you're doing, are you able to provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Table-per-hierarchy mapping and it is possible with both [EDMX](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance) and [code first](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx). To really make it work your subclasses must be mapped because EF must know about their existence to correctly transform discriminator value into correct type. Whole class hierarchy is mapped to single database table.

Comment: So there is no way to do it with my subclasses just having small utility properties?

Comment: No if you want EF to make instances of subclasses for you these sub classes must be mapped. You did the same in DBML - by specifying inheritance in DBML you mapped it.